# Plural repeated field in Protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto

According to Protobuf style-guide [we should use plural forms](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/style#repeated_fields) for repeated fields. But what to do if the message type is plural already or uncountable noun? E.g:

```
message Metadata {
  //...
}
```

Is it ok to use something like

```
message MetadataList {
  repeated Metadata metadata_list = 1
}
```

or it's not and there is a conventional variant for such cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style guides are recommendations intended to encourage consistency so, you should take whatever approach you feel would cause least surprise to other developers.

I'd personally probably use `metadatas`.

Even though it's slightly jarring, I think it's more clear than `metadata` that it denotes a repeated field and, in the vernacular, only purists tend to be sticklers about (meta)datum and (meta)data so the distinction between the singular and plural is otherwise lost.